# How to fix variable input delay when assigning a variable value?

Tags: flutter

I'm making a screen to upload a PDF file that shows a Page count of the PDF file. But whenever I get the PDF file. The screen doesn't show the Page count immediately. Here's the view of the screen.

[image: When the PDF is not yet selected]

[image: After I select the PDF file but not yet press the upload button]

[image: After I press the upload button]

The first picture is when I have not yet choose a PDF file, the second picture is when I already choose the file but not pressed the upload button yet (you can see the page count is still 0), and the last picture is when i pressed the upload button (the page count changed to 16)

Here is my code :

```
class _UploadPageState extends State<UploadPage>{

  PdfDocument docFromFile;

  String _fileName;
  FileType _fileType;
  String _path;
  String _extension = "pdf";
  bool _loadingPath = false;

  int _pageCount = 0;

  bool _visible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fileType = FileType.CUSTOM;
  }

  void toggle() {
    setState(() {
      if(_loadingPath == false){
        _visible = true;
      }
      else{
        _visible = true;
      }
    });

    _getDocument();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(_path != null){
      _visible = true;
    }
    else{
      _visible = false;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Upload PDF"
        ),
      ),

      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 50),

            Center(
              child: _selectFile(),
            ),

            SizedBox(height: 10),

            _uploadButton(),

            SizedBox(height: 40),

            Visibility(
              visible: _visible,
              child: fileDescription(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  Widget _selectFile() {
    return Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 150,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print("Upload File");
          _openFileExplorer();
        },
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _loadingPath ? _fileSelectedLogo(_fileName) : _chooseFileLogo(),
            //_chooseFileLogo(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _chooseFileLogo() {
    return InkWell(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.file_upload, size: 50, color: Colors.blueGrey,),

          Text("Click here to select a PDF file.", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),

          SizedBox(height: 20),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _fileSelectedLogo(String fileName) {
    return Text(
      "File : $fileName",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _uploadButton() {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        print("Upload File");
        _getDocument();
        if(_path != null){
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return UploadDialog(
                title: _pageCount.toString(),
                description: "Test"
              );
            }
          );
        } else{
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return CancelDialog();
              }
          );
        }
      },
      color: Colors.blue,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      child: Text("Upload File"),
    );
  }

  Widget fileDescription() {
    String fn;
    String pc;

    if(_path != null){
      fn = "File Name : $_fileName" ;
      pc = "Page Count : ${_pageCount.toString()}";
    }else{
      fn = "File Name :";
      pc = "Page Count : ";
    }

    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Wrap(
        direction: Axis.vertical,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(fn),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Text(pc),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _openFileExplorer() async{
    _path = await FilePicker.getFilePath(type: _fileType, fileExtension: _extension);
    if(!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      if (_path != null) {
        _loadingPath = true;
        _fileName = _path.split('/').last;
      }
    });
  }

  void _getDocument() async{
    if(_path != null){
      docFromFile = await PdfDocument.openFile(_path);
      setState(() {
        _pageCount = docFromFile.pageCount;
      });
      print(docFromFile.pageCount.toString());
      Toast.show("Page Count : ${docFromFile.pageCount.toString()}",
          context,
          duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: Toast.BOTTOM
      );
    }
    else{
      print("Document not yet fetched.");
      Toast.show("Document not yet fetched.",
          context,
          duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: Toast.BOTTOM
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I've been looking for answers but have yet to found one. I'm new to flutter as well so I'm not sure where did I do wrong. If you need more code I'll provide it to you, and any answers are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You need to `await _openFileExplorer();` and `await _getDocument();` 
code snippet

```
Widget _selectFile() {
    return Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 150,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () async {
          print("Upload File");
          await _openFileExplorer();
          await _getDocument();
        },
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:toast/toast.dart';
import 'package:pdf_render/pdf_render.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: UploadPage(),
    );
  }
}

class UploadPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UploadPageState createState() => _UploadPageState();
}

class _UploadPageState extends State<UploadPage> {
  PdfDocument docFromFile;

  String _fileName;
  FileType _fileType;
  String _path;
  String _extension = "pdf";
  bool _loadingPath = false;

  int _pageCount = 0;

  bool _visible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fileType = FileType.CUSTOM;
  }

  void toggle() {
    setState(() {
      if (_loadingPath == false) {
        _visible = true;
      } else {
        _visible = true;
      }
    });

    _getDocument();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_path != null) {
      _visible = true;
    } else {
      _visible = false;
    }

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Upload PDF"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 50),
              Center(
                child: _selectFile(),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              _uploadButton(),
              SizedBox(height: 40),
              Visibility(
                visible: _visible,
                child: fileDescription(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  Widget _selectFile() {
    return Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 150,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () async {
          print("Upload File");
          await _openFileExplorer();
          await _getDocument();
        },
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _loadingPath ? _fileSelectedLogo(_fileName) : _chooseFileLogo(),
            //_chooseFileLogo(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _chooseFileLogo() {
    return InkWell(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.file_upload,
            size: 50,
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
          ),
          Text("Click here to select a PDF file.",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _fileSelectedLogo(String fileName) {
    return Text(
      "File : $fileName",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _uploadButton() {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        print("Upload File");
        _getDocument();
        if (_path != null) {
          /*showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return UploadDialog(
                    title: _pageCount.toString(),
                    description: "Test"
                );
              }
          );*/
        } else {
          /*showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return CancelDialog();
              }
          );*/
        }
      },
      color: Colors.blue,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      child: Text("Upload File"),
    );
  }

  Widget fileDescription() {
    String fn;
    String pc;

    if (_path != null) {
      fn = "File Name : $_fileName";
      pc = "Page Count : ${_pageCount.toString()}";
    } else {
      fn = "File Name :";
      pc = "Page Count : ";
    }

    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Wrap(
        direction: Axis.vertical,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(fn),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Text(pc),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _openFileExplorer() async {
    _path = await FilePicker.getFilePath(
        type: _fileType, fileExtension: _extension);
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      if (_path != null) {
        _loadingPath = true;
        _fileName = _path.split('/').last;
      }
    });
  }

  void _getDocument() async {
    if (_path != null) {
      docFromFile = await PdfDocument.openFile(_path);
      setState(() {
        _pageCount = docFromFile.pageCount;
      });
      print(docFromFile.pageCount.toString());
      Toast.show("Page Count : ${docFromFile.pageCount.toString()}", context,
          duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
    } else {
      print("Document not yet fetched.");
      Toast.show("Document not yet fetched.", context,
          duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
    }
  }
}
```